# Colimits of n-fold categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, internal-categories

An [$n$-fold category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-fold+category) is an internal category in the category of $(n-1)$-fold categories (and a $0$-fold category is just a Set).

General results about internal categories assure that the category of $n$-fold categories is cartesian closed. Is something known about colimits of $n$-fold categories?

Intuitively, finite coproducts exist. What about coequalizers?

Comment: Colimits in the strict sense exist, for general reasons. What would be more interesting is non-strict colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin  Can I ask you what those general reasons are?

Comment: The category of internal categories in a locally presentable category is again a locally presentable category. In particular, it is has colimits.

Comment: Following the (external construcion) in Wolff, H. V-cat and V-graph, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 4 (1974), 123—135,  rewrite this proof in internal terms...